# putty: auto connect and run a set of comamnd

Tags: ssh, putty

I am using putty to ssh to a server (Ubuntu 20.04) and run 3 commands. However, sometimes the connection is broken and I need to shutdown putty and restart manually.

Is there any method that I can use to tell putty (or an alternative program) to:

- auto-reconnect if disconnected.
- after connection, run 3 pre-defined commands.

Many thanks.

Comment: I have checked this post before, but it does not help to auto run some commands. Furthermore, the post is ten years ago ... I am not sure if the answers are still valid.

Comment: It is still valid. + If you knew this question before posting yours, you should have mentioned it, instead of having people look for it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to mention